# Use WSS 3.0 to connect to Sharepoint 2007

Tags: 2007, wss-3.0, content-query-web-part

I have the Intranet on Sharepoint 2007 Standard and want to setup a separate server with Windows Sharepoint Services 3.0 that would mirror (Just view, no editing) a specific Site. Is this at all possible?

Comment: There may be options within SharePoint itself.  Can explain the purpose behind this?

Comment: We want to display the WSS site view on the Internet. All changes will be made on the Intranet side.

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious solution would be to create a new Web Application that uses Forms Authentication and allows for Anonymous users but point it to the same content database.  This web application could be presented to the internet and would be read-only as no users in that authentication domain would have any permissions.

The other option that requires more manual steps would be to create a separate SharePoint farm that can face the Internet and then manually copy the content database from your internal SharePoint site to the external site but mark the restored database itself as Read-Only.  You would then set up a web application and point it to that restored database.  You would need to move the database periodically in order to keep the internet content current.  If you really wanted to get creative, you could also investigate Log Shipping or some other database replication options.

You will also need to check your licensing as SharePoint requires a specific license in order for it to be presented on the public internet.

Comment: If I create a seperate Farm would this be database restore be compatible from MOSS 2007 to WSS 3.0?

Comment: Theoretically, it is possible provided that you are not using any MOSS-specific features/templates in the the site(s) in that content DB.  It also requires that both WSS and MOSS be patched to precisely the same Service Pack and Cumulative Update

Comment: In my case I just want a backup of a specific site not the whole Intranet. Is this possible? Thanks.

Comment: By 'site' do you mean a specific site/web an actual proper Site Collection, or a Web Application?  The options available will vary based on the scope of the content

Comment: An actual "Sharepoint Site".

Answer (score 0):

I'd imagine you could do some sort of "Proxy", visiting the SharePoint 2007 site via HttpWebRequest objects in .NET, scrape the results and re-image them on your WSS3 site via web part.  Not the most elegant solution and the development work would be quite significant, but it would work.